# Pandas Multiindex - Perform Operation on Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe where I'd like to perform an operation on each group based on the minimum value of one of the columns.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd
d={'name':['foo','foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar','baz', 'baz'],
   'grp':[1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 8, 2, 4], 
   'val':[50, 100, 200, 25, 100, 200, 75, 150]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index(['name', 'grp'], inplace=True)
df
```

Gives me a dataframe like this:

```
          val
name grp
foo  1     50
     2    100
     4    200
bar  1     25
     4    100
     8    200
baz  2     75
     4    150
```

What I'd like to do is perform an operation on each value for each 'grp' grouping based on the lowest value in 'grp'.  For example, normalize each 'val' by dividing each one in the group by the lowest value to get something like this:

```
          val
name grp
foo  1     50  1
     2    100  2
     4    200  4
bar  1     25  1
     4    100  4
     8    200  8
baz  2     75  1
     4    150  2
```

Note that the calculation is performed on the 'val' column, but based on the minimum 'grp' number's 'val' value.  I'm struggling with finding a good way to loop through this, so thanks for any pointers.
I'm using Python v3.6 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `div` with `level`

```
df.div(df.min(level=[0]),level='name')
Out[157]: 
          val
name grp     
foo  1    1.0
     2    2.0
     4    4.0
bar  1    1.0
     4    4.0
     8    8.0
baz  2    1.0
     4    2.0
```

Comment: Many thanks to @Wen and to @Coldspeed for their answers.  This was much simpler than what I was trying to do.  My data was was in a dataframe which was much more complex, and I wanted to add the result of the calculation into a new column so ended up with something like this: `df['ratio'] = df[['val']].div(df[['val']].min(level=[0]),level='name')`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to `groupby` and then `transform` on `min`:

```
df /= df.groupby(level=0).transform('min')
df

          val
name grp     
foo  1    1.0
     2    2.0
     4    4.0
bar  1    1.0
     4    4.0
     8    8.0
baz  2    1.0
     4    2.0
```

For integer divison, replace `/=` by `//=`.